# accessing a layout(.xml) from a java class in android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have this layout (activity_main2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

as you see it is calling another layout (app_bar_main2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this one is calling another layout (content_main2.xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dear user!"
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName_Main"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a java class (Welcome.Java) which calls "activity_main2.xml" in "onCreate" by the following code:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
```

Now I want to access the TextView , in content_main2.xml from the Welcome.Java , and set the text of TextView to the real username which I have read from database. 
would you please guide me how to point to the TextView and set its value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName_Main);
userName.setText("YOUR_USERNAME");
```

Comment: thanks! how could I ask this stupid question! maybe too much coding from 5 am till now (evening) has made me crazy!